# Silverlight Visual Studio XAML Design view not working

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I have installed visual studio 2008 sp1, silverlight tools, silverlight sdk, silverlight toolkit 2009 but still when I open silverlight application silverlight tools are not showing on my tool window as well as silverlight XAML Design view(color code formate) is not working.
Whole xaml code is coming in black color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open visual studio comand prompt and write this command
**..VC>devenv /resetskippkgs**
press enter it would take 8 sec to reset settings.